# Problem with Mail System/SwiftMailer

Tags: 8, emails

In the submitForm of some form of my custom module, an  email is sent this way:

```
$sTo = 'eric.falzon@free.fr';
$sBcc = _setListOfRecipients();
$aParams = array($sBcc, $rpYear);
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('association', 'renewmembershipfirst', $sTo, 'fr', $aParams);
```

In my custom module, there is

```
function association_mail($key, &$message, $aParams)
{
    $sFrom = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
    $message['from'] = $sFrom;
    $message['headers'] = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html',
        'bcc' => $aParams[0],
        'From' => $sFrom,
        'Sender' => $sFrom,
        'Return-Path' => $sFrom,
    );
    switch ($key) {
        case 'renewmembershipfirst':
            $message['subject'] = '[le Jardin de Poissy] Renouvellement d\'adhésion';
            $sBody = "<b>" . $aParams[1] . "</b>";
            $message['body'][] = check_markup(nl2br($sBody), 'full_html');
            break;
    }
}
```

The settings of mailsystem are these:
[image]

And in my theme templates folder (mysite/web/themes/contrib/mayo/templates/), there is my email template swiftmailer--association--renewmembershipfirst.html.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css"> body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table width="800px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <p>
                        Chers adh&eacute;rents du <strong>Jardin de Poissy</strong>,<br>
                        <br>
                        La p&eacute;riode de renouvellement des adh&eacute;sions pour {{ body }} est ouverte !<br>
                        <br>
                        Pour nous signaler votre décision :
                    <ul>
                        <li>vous suivez ce <a href="{{ url('association.renew_membership') }}">{{ 'lien'|t }}</a>,</li>
                        <li>vous indiquez votre choix (Non, Oui),</li>
                        <li>vous soumettez.</li>
                    </ul>
                    En cas de réponse positive, la soumission déclenche le téléchargement de votre bulletin
                    d'adhésion.<br>
                    Vous l'imprimez et vous nous l'envoyez accompagné de votre règlement.<br>
                    <br>
                    Merci d'avance,<br>
                    <strong>Le Jardin de Poissy</strong><br><br>
                    P.-S. Ce courriel a été envoyé automatiquement. Merci de ne pas y répondre.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The email is sent (and received). Everything is OK (From, To, Bcc, Subject, Body).
But (there is a but), I get this notice message

```
Notice: Undefined index: filter_format in Drupal\swiftmailer\Plugin\Mail\SwiftMailer->massageMessageBody() (line 630 of modules/contrib/swiftmailer/src/Plugin/Mail/SwiftMailer.php).
Drupal\swiftmailer\Plugin\Mail\SwiftMailer->massageMessageBody(Array) (Line: 107)
Drupal\swiftmailer\Plugin\Mail\SwiftMailer->format(Array) (Line: 43)
Drupal\mailsystem\Adapter->format(Array) (Line: 287)
Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager->doMail('association', 'renewmembershipfirst', 'eric.falzon@free.fr', 'fr', Array, NULL, 1) (Line: 179)
Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager->Drupal\Core\Mail\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 180)
Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager->mail('association', 'renewmembershipfirst', 'eric.falzon@free.fr', 'fr', Array, NULL, 1) (Line: 73)
Drupal\mailsystem\MailsystemManager->mail('association', 'renewmembershipfirst', 'eric.falzon@free.fr', 'fr', Array) (Line: 301)
Drupal\association\Form\RenewMembership->executeActions(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 589)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('renew_membership', Array, Object) (Line: 318)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('renew_membership', Object) (Line: 93)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing a key in the message body array? That is basically what the notice is saying on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged a litte bit in /swiftmailer/src/Plugin/Mail/SwiftMailer.php:

```
public function massageMessageBody(array $message) {
    // Get default mail line endings and merge all lines in the e-mail body
    // separated by the mail line endings. Keep Markup objects and escape others
    // and then treat the result as safe markup.
    $line_endings = Settings::get('mail_line_endings', PHP_EOL);
    $applicable_format = $this->getApplicableFormat($message);
    $filter_format = $this->config['message']['filter_format'];
    $message['body'] = Markup::create(implode($line_endings, array_map(function ($body) use ($applicable_format, $filter_format) {
```

I went to $this->config['message'] with Devel' config editor:

```
format: text/html
respect_format: true
convert_mode: true
character_set: UTF-8
```

which stands probably for
[image]
But no trace of 'filter_format'.
Comparing with another D8 site I have with similar configuration, I found that what was missing is this entry in swiftmailer config: `filter_format: plain_text`.
I added it with Devel and now everything is OK: no more `Notice: Undefined index: filter_format in Drupal\swiftmailer\Plugin\Mail\SwiftMailer`.

But i have no clue of where this setting can be done thru UI.
Any idea?

Comment: I had this same problem without a custom module and found [a patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer/issues/2948607) in the issue queue. There's also an [open issue with a needs work patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer/issues/3016912) to expose the filter format setting in the UI.